# Maven -- Why are dependencies versions not overwritten?

Tags: spring-boot, maven

My project depends on spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb and I just want to upgrade mongodb driver's version. Here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.9</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is final dependency tree:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree (default-cli) @ demo ---
[INFO] com.demo:demo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:jar:4.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mongodb:bson:jar:4.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:jar:4.2.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.5.9:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.33:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.15:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.15:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.28:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:3.2.8:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.15:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.15:compile
[INFO]       |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.15:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.15:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.15:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.5.8:compile
[INFO]       \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.33:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My question is why bson and mongodb-driver-core's version are still 4.2.3 instead of 4.5.0. mongodb-driver-sync will depends on bson and mongodb-driver-core, and the versions are 4.5.0. Here is the pom of mongodb-driver-sync.

```
<project>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
  <version>4.5.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Show the full pom file of your project...

Comment: Added. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Because `spring-boot-starter-parent` inherits from `spring-boot-dependencies`, which defines

```xml
<mongodb.version>4.2.3</mongodb.version>
```

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <!-- ... -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>${mongodb.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- ... -->
</dependencyManagement>
```

You need to [override the property in your pom](https://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-overriding-versions.html) if you want to upgrade it independently:

```xml
<mongodb.version>4.5.0</mongodb.version>
```

Or wait for the Spring Boot 2.7.0 release, which upgrades Mongo to 4.5.0.

Comment: I have tried add <mongodb.version>4.5.0</mongodb.version>, but I met another issue. The mongo related jars versions in this project(demo) are what I expected. I have another project named subdemo which depends on demo. In subdemo, mongo related jars versions come back to 4.2.3 not 4.5.0.
```
<project>
  <groupId>com.subdemo</groupId>
  <artifactId>subdemo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
      <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: @maotang it will have cached demo:0.0.1. You need to add -SNAPSHOT to the version if you are making changes without incrementing the version.